# how to send parameter collection in Postman tool to invoke POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, postman

How do I send parameters as collection to invoke a POST method?

I have a web API url pointing to POST method which takes a collection as an input parameter.

I wanted to invoke this method using postman tool.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your webapi method looks like this:

```
public void Post([FromBody]IEnumerable<string> values)
```

You can simply use POSTman like this

[image]

You will need to set the content-type header to application/json:

[image]

Comment: I have set up postman as you suggested but keep getting a json error back: "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.".  Have you tested your solution to ensure that it works using the webapi signature that you added or have I done something wrong?

Comment: If I specify a header of "Content-Type" "application/json", click the raw tab and enter ["one", "two"] it appears to work, but I can't get it to work as you have suggested in your solution.

Comment: missed that bit out, have edited answer to reflect this

Comment: Add [FromBody] - see my updated answer - `public void Post([FromBody]IEnumerable<string> values)`